# Run login script from .NET application

Tags: .net, active-directory, login-script

I am writing a small utility that, among other things, will allow the user to run his/her logon script.  It is a .NET application that will run on Windows XP/Vista/7 PCs that are joined to an active directory domain.  The PCs belong to different organizational units and will be running different scripts.

Is there an environment variable that I can query that will tell me the script that ran when the user logged on?  Or will I have to include it in the config file and make sure that every PC is pointed to the correct script?

Comment: From your comment below, it seems you have multiple domains.  Are they all in a single forest or do you have lots of separate forests?

Comment: Separate forests.  We are a consulting company and the application is for our clients, so we have to deal with completely separate networks

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1271575.aspx

Simply use Active Directory.

Here's some related C#/VB.NET code to help you with the .NET aspects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8wxt72e(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but going through LDAP still requires that I provide a domain-specific connection string.  This idea is to do everything without having to provide configuration data.  Thank for the reply though